# ANOVA or test to distinguish treatment groups

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, methodology, treatment-effect

I have two lots of questions which should be pretty straight forward to solve with an ANOVA or as studies previously used Wilcoxon-Mann Whitney matched pairs. However I'm not quite sure what to tell R.

I'm looking at color change over time. I have two lots of outcomes a before and after so, Day 0 (before they are placed on the treatment) and Week 8 (after treatment). See below for how it is laid out

However I want see if there is a significant difference in day 0 and week 8 depending on the treatment so black or white and the vision model so "pol" or "pea" and the species "fur" or "shore" while also asking R to distinguish between "huevalue" or "lumvalue" .

I did try the Wilcoxon test mentioned above but I couldn't figure out how to get it to take into account all mentioned above.

[image]